# How would I solve the following problem involving elementary matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

> Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&5\\ 7&4\end{pmatrix}$.
>
> 1) Write $A$ as a product of $4$ elementary matrices.
>
> 2) Write $A^{-1}$ as a product of $4$ elementary matrices.

**My work**. I have managed to find $A^{-1}$, which came out to be this:

\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{4}{35}&\frac{1}{7}\\ \frac{1}{5}&0\end{pmatrix}

However, I am struggling to figure out how I would split each of these matrices into $4$ elementary matrices. Any help?

Comment: Try first solving either the problem "Write $A$ as a product of elementary matrices" or the problem "Write $A^{-1}$ as a product of elementary matrices".

Comment: Once you write $A$ as a product of four elementary matrices, the product for $A^{-1}$ is an immediate consequence (inverse of an elementary matrix is an elementary matrix of the same type).

Comment: A key idea is that if you row reduce your matrix to the identity matrix, each step of the row reduction can be expressed as multiplying on the left by an elementary matrix. So first perform the row reduction. Express each step of the reduction as multiplying by an elementary matrix. This will give you an equation $E_n \cdots E_1 A =I$, so you're almost done.

Answer (score 1):

For $a\not=0$ we have that
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & 0 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ c & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -bc/a \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b/a \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
then $A^{−1}$ is a product of 4 elementary matrices with $a=-4/35$, $b=1/7$, and $c=1/5$.

Note that [elementary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) generate a group of invertible matrices. Hence if $A^{-1}=E_1E_2E_3E_4$ where $E_i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$ are some elementary matrices then $A=E_4^{-1}E_3^{-1}E_2^{-1}E_1^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I will write $E_1,E_2,\cdots$ to denote some elementary matrices. You are wanting to find $E_1E_2\cdots E_n A =I$ and then you can simply inverse all of these one at a time from the left:
$$E_1^{-1}E_1E_2\cdots E_n A=E_1^{-1}I\iff E_2\cdots E_nA=E_1^{-1}$$
$$\iff A= E_n^{-1}E_{n-1}^{-1}\cdots E_1^{-1}$$

Then to find $A^{-1}$, what do you know about inverse of products?

---

As a first step though. We can row swap:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}7&4\\ 0&5\end{bmatrix}$$
Then you need two more row operations and you are done.