# How would I solve the following question involving elementary matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}0&5\\ 7&4\end{pmatrix}$$

(i) Write $A$ as a product of 4 elementary matrices.

(ii) Write $A^{-1}$ as a product of 4 elementary matrices.

I have managed to solve for $A^{-1}$, which is:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{4}{35}&\frac{1}{7}\\ \frac{1}{5}&0\end{pmatrix}$$

But I am struggling to figure out how I would split each of these into 4 elementary matrices.

I know that if I can solve the 4 elementary matrices of one of them, I just need to invert them to get the elementary matrices of the other.

Any help?

Comment: You asked the same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452518/how-would-i-solve-the-following-problem-involving-elementary-matrices

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Let $ A = \begin{pmatrix}0&5\\ 7&4\end{pmatrix}$.

Divide first row of $A$ by $5$.

Perform $R_2 - 4R_1$.

Divide the second row by $7$.

There is also one more step to reduce it to the identity matrix.

Write down the elementary matrices corresponds to these operations.